# Beamer - frametitle - How to add '\'?

Tags: beamer, titles

How to add '\' in frametitle ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]%
\frametitle{$find \ldots -exec \ldots \ ;$} %How to make "\;" in title ?
\begin{semiverbatim}
$ find -name '*.pdf' -exec cp -v '\{\}' ../pdfs \\;
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\textbackslash` to insert a `\\` as text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using math mode you need to write `\backslash`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]%
    \frametitle{$find \ldots -exec \ldots \backslash ;$} %How to make "\;" in title ?
    \begin{semiverbatim}
    $ find -name '*.pdf' -exec cp -v '\{\}' ../pdfs \\;
    \end{semiverbatim}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Maybe you could consider using `listings` Package, which provides an rich environment for typesetting code.

Answer (score 3):

Using math mode for that frame title is rather strange, considering that you're probably using typewriter type for the `semiverbatim` environment:

```
\frametitle{\texttt{\$ find ... -exec ... \textbackslash;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). This website will try to recognize a symbol you draw with your mouse and tell you *mathmode* and *textmode* alternatives to enter this symbol. Also see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol).

For a drawn `\`, DeTeXify comes up with

- `\textbackslash` textmode
- `\setminus` mathmode
- `\backslash` mathmode
- `\usepackage{amssymb} \backprime` mathmode
- `\usepackage{amssymb} \smallsetminus` mathmode